# Different locks for a singleton class

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, synchronization

I have a singleton class that contains 3 HashMap. Each hashmap acts like a pool. I put the unused entries in there. I encountered a concurrency modification exception so I was planning to implement synchronization on them. My problem is if I use the same lock for all of them, there would possibly be a performance issue. Because when I create an entry for that pool, it is through a web service call. Since I only need that each hashmap doesn't run concurrently, is it ok to create 3 object locks for them?

Comment: "is it ok to create 3 object locks for each hashmap" - Not only ok but necessary.

Comment: @Fildor What's wrong with a single shared lock?

Comment: @EldonHipolito You can use the actual map objects as locks if you want.

Comment: @shmosel: OP writes, he needs each of the three Maps to be synchronized separately ... If you know how to do that with one single shared lock then show me, please. I would be interested in how that's done.

Comment: @shmosel *Since I only need that each hashmap doesn't run concurrently* why block all 3 of them, seems like the OP wants to block only one a time

Comment: @EldonHipolito show some code or give a bit more context...

Comment: @shmosel I did not mention it explicitly but I have actually 6 maps. The maps are partners therefore I just mentioned that I have 3 maps to simplify my question.

Comment: @Fildor *I only need that each hashmap doesn't run concurrently* means we want to disallow concurrent access to each individual map. As far as thread safety goes, a single lock accomplishes that goal. OP's question is whether it's possible to reduce contention by using separate locks. The answer is it's ok but *not* strictly necessary.

Comment: Why not use [ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: @shmosel Then my interpretation was different. If you put it that way, you are right, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

> The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without contention.

Try to tune performance with concurrencyLevel parameter.

Comment: The tuning really shouldn't be necessary in most circumstances @Alexey.  I've written hundreds of CHM implementations and never had to tune anything.